# AsyncTask not create GridView using BaseAdpter

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

Im new to android development have very basic knowledge of this whatever i have achieved till now is achieved using this website or youtube videos i'm stuck in AsyncTask (Earlier i was using .get() on Create View and it was working fine but UI Was blocked until task is finished. To Avoid UI Blocking i was advice to remove .get() function from OnCreateView() function now after removing this im not being able to get any data from AsyncTask). I did that but now i'm not being able to create view i did lots of research but unable to get this strength

Here is my Codes Please Help how to create view from this

OnCreateView() :-

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View GView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    progressBarHolder = (FrameLayout) GView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarHolder);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) GView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),Json_String,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String finalResult = null;
    try{
        finalResult = String.valueOf(new JSONTask().execute("https://www.example.in/android_api/dashboard_data",JsonData()));
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),Json_String,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        JSONObject parentObject = null;
        parentObject = new JSONObject(finalResult);
        if(((String) parentObject.names().get(0)).matches("error")){
            JSONObject jObj = parentObject.getJSONObject("error");
            errorThrow(jObj.getString("Description"));
        } else if(((String) parentObject.names().get(0)).matches("success")){
            JSONObject jObj = parentObject.getJSONObject("success");
            JSONArray arrajson = jObj.getJSONArray("data");
            String arrayCount = Integer.toString(arrajson.length());
            String[] type = new String[arrajson.length()];
            Integer[] count = new Integer[arrajson.length()];
            for (int i=0; i<arrajson.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = arrajson.getJSONObject(i);
                type[i] = jsonObject.getString("type");
                count[i] = jsonObject.getInt("count");
            }
            CustomAdpter customAdpter = new CustomAdpter(DashboardFragment.this,type,count);
            gridView.setAdapter(customAdpter);
            return GView;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return GView;
}
```

Base Adapter Code :-

```
    class CustomAdpter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] type;
    Integer[] count;
    public CustomAdpter(DashboardFragment dashboardFragment, String[] type, Integer[] count){
        this.count = count;
        this.type = type;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return type.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_single_itme,null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(count[i]));
        textView1.setText(type[i]);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Booking Item Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

AsyncTask Code :-

```
    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    int progress;
    public JSONTask(){
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(),"Loading","Loading Data...",true,false);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        final String finalJson = params[1];
        String json = finalJson;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("A-APK-API", "******");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic **:**");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.connect();

            OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter streams =  new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8");
            stream.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            stream.close();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection != null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Json_String = result;
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Please help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a result from asynctask when you dont use .get().

So change that statement. Start only the asynctask.

Then put all the code after that line in onPostExecute() of the AsyncTask.

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

you should change way you are creating the Adapter and attaching
you should do this

1.At first get the data in List,ArrayList etc. via `AsyncTask`, `doInBackGround` method

2. then on the `onPostExecute` method retrieve the data and create Adapter and attach it to your View
3. While you are getting data you can show some `ProgressDialog`.
4. If your `AsyncTask` is in other separate class then use interface to get the data from your `AsyncTask` class
   look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47373959/8197737